# Weighted average. How to get the weight?

Tags: metric-spaces, average

I want to find a good metric to measure the overtime of appointments in a hospital across different days. For example, there are only 2 kinds of appointments A and B. A is supposed to take 30min and B is supposed to take $40$min (ideally).

In reality:

On Monday, there are 3 A scheduled actually taking 35, 40, 28 min.
           there are 2 B scheduled actually taking 45, 50 min.

On Tuesday, there are 1 A scheduled actually taking 36min.
            there are 2 B scheduled actually taking 37, 42min.

I want to find a good metric to measure the overtime. At first, I used average overtime.

For Monday, it is $[(35-30)+(40-30)+(28-30)+(45-40)+(50-40)]/5$

For Tuesday, it is $[(36-30)+(37-40)+(42-40)]/3$

But then I realized I count type A and B equally. Think an actual overtime $10$min for A is definitely worse than $10$min overtime for B (since ideally A should take 30min and B 40min). That's my point. I am thinking to do a weighted average but could not get the best (reasonable) weight. Please help how to get the weight or other good metric. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just divide the overtimes by the ideal time (almost kind of like percent error). So for Monday, it would be

$[(35-30)/30 +(40-30)/30$ +$(28-30)/30$ +$(30-40)/40 +(45-40)/40 +(50-40)/40]/5$. For Tuesday, it would be $[(36-30)/30 +(37-40)/40 +(42-40)/40]/3$.
I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: I agree this is a reasonable solution. But in this case, there is no way to measure how better Tuesday (answer=0.058) compared to Monday (answer = 0.112). In other words, it is not a normalized result.

Comment: How about instead of comparing Monday to Tuesday, compare A to B?

Comment: I am sorry but I have to measure across days.

Comment: Can you keep the results for A and B separate across the days? As in compare appointments A across days and then compare appointments B across days?

Comment: Basically I need to measure the performance of each day.

Comment: When you say weighted metric, do you mean Appointment B is weighted more than Appointment A?

Comment: I mean "Think an actual overtime 10min for A is definitely worse than 10min overtime for B (since ideally A should take 30min and B 40min)". 30 + 10 is worse than 40+10.

Comment: If that's what you want, I think my solution should work ... 10/30 > 10/40.